# How to shrink a large file in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a file that I want to truncate to 2kb (i.e. keep the first 2kb of data, get rid of the rest). How can I do this with bash?

Comment: This isn't really a bash question -- it's more an operating system question. `bash` itself doesn't have any way to do a truncate operation built-in; rather, you'd be using bash to call a tool shipped with your operating system, such as `truncate` or `dd`. Which of those tools are available, and which options they have, depends on your OS -- which you haven't specified here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command is (surprise, surprise) [`truncate`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/truncate).

```
truncate -s 2KB file
```

Comment: That said, this is a Linuxism, and certainly not guaranteed to be present on all systems where bash is supported.

Answer (score 4):

The standards-compliant way to do this (not relying on any Linux-only tools such as `truncate`) is to use `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=/file/to/truncate seek=1 bs=2k
```

Unlike the other `dd` answer, which merely copies the first 2k of a file, this one truncates the target file at that point.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this in pure `bash`:

```
IFS= read -r -n 2048 first2k < file
printf "%s" "$first2k" > file
```

but using `dd` is a much better idea. For one, it's more likely to be atomic; it's possible an external process could modify the first 2048 bytes of `file` after `read`, but before the `printf`. Second, it's less verbose :)

You can also use `read`'s default variable `REPLY`, which does not require setting `IFS` to avoid word splitting:

```
read -r -n 2048 < file
printf "%s" "$REPLY" > file
```

Comment: Instead of unsetting IFS, why not just use the implied `REPLY` name? If you don't set a name, `REPLY` does not trim whitespace.

Comment: I was going to make that edit, but decided to keep `first2k` as a more descriptive variable name for the question. I'll add the default, too. (Also, I just learned about the word-splitting only affecting explicit names the other day, I think from one of your answers or comments.)

Comment: Implicit is better than explic... no wait.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dd`:

```
dd if=yourfile of=firstLump bs=2k count=1
```

if = the input file

of = the output file

bs = blocksize

count = number of blocks

Available on Linux AND Mac OSX.

Comment: "use dd" is indeed the right answer if trying to be portable. However, this particular use is **not** a truncate-in-place operation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh, I wasn't aware that it could :-) And I can't see it in my Mac's manpages. Please enlighten me/us! Feel free to add yor own answer or edit mine as you please. Thank you.

Comment: I've added another answer.